# Top aligned tabular: \cline equivalent of \firsthline (or \firstcline)

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, rules

When aligning `tabular` environments with the `[t]` option, one can use `\firsthline` (from the array package) instead of `\hline` when a line is required at the top of the table. Like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
Tabular with hline: 
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
  \hline A & B \\ C & D \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
and with firsthline:
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
  \firsthline A & B \\ C & D \\ \lasthline
\end{tabular}
```

But what if I want only some cells of the first line to have a line above them, like this:

```
Tabular with cline:
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
  \cline{2-2} A & B \\ C & D \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
and what it should look like:
\raisebox{.8em}{
  \begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
    \cline{2-2} A & B \\ C & D \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

And the compiled result:

[image: Vertical alignment problem illustrated]

Is there any easy way to achieve this effect without manually tweaking the vertical offset with `\raisebox`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a command `\firscline` similar to `\firsthline` but using `\cline` instead of `\hline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\firstcline}[1]{%
  \multicolumn1c{%
    \global\backup@length\ht\@arstrutbox
    \global\advance\backup@length\dp\@arstrutbox
    \global\advance\backup@length\arrayrulewidth
     \raise\extratabsurround\copy\@arstrutbox
    }\\[-\backup@length]\cline{#1}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Tabular with \verb+\hline+: 
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
  \hline A & B \\ C & D \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
and with \verb+\firstcline+:
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
  \firstcline{1-1} A & B \\ C & D \\ \lasthline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
  \firstcline{2-2} A & B \\ C & D \\ \lasthline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's a whole lot of @s in there. I think that definition would make a sensible addition to the array package.

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you use `\hline` and `cline` directly with the expected output. Moreover, you can write `\cline{2}` instead of `\cline{2-2}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\verb|{NiceTabular}| with \verb|\hline|:\quad
\begin{NiceTabular}[t]{ll}
  \hline A & B \\ C & D \\ \hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\bigskip
\verb|{NiceTabular}| with \verb|\cline|:\quad 
\begin{NiceTabular}[t]{ll}
  \cline{2} A & B \\ C & D \\ \hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Ouput of the above code]